# Firebase no index defined even when using .indexOn correctly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I get an error message:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "author" at /questions to your security rules for better performance.

my firebase rules :

```
"questions": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
        ".indexOn": ["category,author"]
    },
```

My firebase data :

```
 "questions" : {
    "-Ls1LfayKF9TUg20ByPE" : {
      "question" : "1",
      "timestamp" : 1571997530706,
      "author" : "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12"
    },
    "-Ls1Lj_OG4lo11r3WQzF" : {
      "question" : "2",
      "timestamp" : 1571997546988,
      "author" : "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12"
    },
```

My code :

```
const ref = FirebaseRef.child('questions')
ref.orderByChild('author').equalTo(UID).limitToLast(this.state.limit)
      .on("child_added", snapshot => {
       console.log("FireB ",snapshot)
    var items = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      items.push({
        key: child.key,
        ...child.val()
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.indexOn` can be an array of string values. You now actually have only one string value in there.

So replace:

```
".indexOn": ["category,author"]
```

With:

```
".indexOn": ["category", "author"]
```